# Getting data from previous run in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm creating a service in c# that gets a file via HttpWebRequest. Now, I want to keep/cache this file so, if the service is stopped and run again it can use this file again. However, I don't want to save it on the local disk and use it again. Basically I want the response content to be saved somewhere other than local disk.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
                        _options.CurrentValue.HttpWebRequest+"/GetFile/GetLatestFileForIinService?header=" + _fileHeader);
_options.OnChange((options) =>
{
    request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
        options.HttpWebRequest + "/GetFile/GetLatestFileForIinService?header=" + _fileHeader);
});
request.Method = "GET";
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
request.Accept = "*/*";
request.ContentType = "text/csv";
request.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=IinRanges-2021119.csv");

using WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
using Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
if (stream == null) return;
using StreamReader sr99 = new(stream, Encoding.ASCII);
var responseContent = sr99.ReadToEnd();
```

The requirement arises because this service doesn't have permissions to write on the disk and it's needed to be that way.  Also this service will be run by different machines so for example shutting it down on 1 machine and running it on another so I want the previous file to survive the restart of the service.

Comment: Could you give some more detail as to why you cannot save the file to disk? Why do you have this requirement?

Comment: Its simply because this service doesn't have permissions to write on the disk and its needed to be that way also this service will be run by different machines so for example shutting it down on 1 machine and running it on another so I want the previous file to survive the restart of the service.

Comment: You could always store the result in a global static variable, but this won't help if you need services on different machines to have access to that same variable. If that is the case you will need to use a centralized cache like Redis or even a basic Azure SQL database.

Comment: Even if I don't use the service on different machine only use on the same machine. Will global variables not be erased after restart of the service?

Comment: After reading your requirements carefully, why not cache it in the database? Are you looking for a tutorial for caching into the database?

Comment: Yes, global static variables would be lost. If you need to store them, either you need to write to disk - or store in an online service or database.

Comment: When your app's process is terminated all data in memory including global static variable data is lost.  If you can't store data to disk, then were can you store data?  [Isolated storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/isolated-storage)?  If your service doesn't allow any data to be persisted **at all** then you will need to cache your data elsewhere, such as the original server, or some other server.